# Moodle quiz display modal only during attempt not during review

Tags: jquery, moodle, jscript

I have added a modal form on a question on moodle quiz using the code below:

```
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">

                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <h4>The time allocated for this question is over. Please go to the next page: </h4>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">

                <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next page" class="mod_quiz-next-nav btn btn-primary">

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- /.modal-content -->

    </div>

    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->

</div>

<!-- /.modal -->
```

I would like to make this modal visible only during attempt not during review. Is there any way to achieve using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Use the moodle default javascript modal method.
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/AMD_Modal

```
// Add your modal body content on footer mustache or theme incourse layout file.
  <div id="question-attepmt-popup" class="modal-content" style="display:none">
      <h4>The time allocated for this question is over. Please go to the next page: </h4>
  </div>

  // Place this code on your theme incourse layout file or yourtheme_page_init function. 
    global $PAGE;
    $PAGE->requires->js_amd_inline('
        require(["jquery", "core/modal_factory"], function($, ModalFactory){
            if ( $("body").attr("id") == "page-mod-quiz-attempt" ) {
                ModalFactory.create({
                    type: ModalFactory.types.SAVE_CANCEL, 
                    title: "Delete item", // Your modal title.
                    body: $("#question-attempt-popup"),
                }).then(function(modal) {
                    modal.show();
                })
            }     
        });
    ');
```

If you don't want to show save and cancel buttons, remove this line and use the footer attribute to add your specific buttons.